# How to - Contact form filled out on Vue APP through API > Magento?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives, vue-storefront

### Introduction

I've set up a vue-component on my app, this vue-component is a contact form, it is imported to the header component, and wrapped inside of a modal.

This contact form must submit an acknowledge message and event that this information will send an email to receiving@email.com on the end.

### Question 1

Question: How to trigger an event in vuejs that when this button is triggered, a new HTML block shows with acknowledgment information? My partner and I experienced with Jquery right here, and I am looking for the same results in Vuejs: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLJwxo?editors=1010

We've set up https://logima.io on Vue Storefront, for practicality reasons (Since we're in the business of building webshops for clients, we want to get more in depth and create more groundbreaking results)

You can click on the "Get your App!" A button on the top right corner of the nav.

### Question 2

What's the best approach/practice to make Vue-storefront contact form connect with Magento contact form through API?

Since Vue-storefront works as a shell for Magento through its API, it should, in theory, be possible to setup up a form on Magento, configure API and make a bridge between the Vue APP and Magento so that you don't need to set up SMTP or other stuff directly for the instance your Storefront is on.

To be more clear:

The user fills out a contact form on logima.io > API connects to email form on Magento > Magento form is filled out > Sends an email to receiving address.

This already works with products and orders. We've set up a couple of shops on Vue-storefront using Magento external checkout and the API works perfectly. I'm just wondering how to actually modify or create new strings of code so that shell contact form can fill out Magento form through existing API.

### HTML

```
    <div id="app">

  <form class="vue-form" @submit.prevent="submit">

    <div class="error-message">
      <p v-show="!email.valid">Oh, please enter a valid email address.</p>
    </div>

    <fieldset>

        <legend>
          <b>
            We will build you a fast PWA, just let us know your details
          </b>
        </legend>
   <GetBackToYou/>
      <div>
        <label class="label" for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="" v-model="name">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="label" for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required=""
               :class="{ email , error: !email.valid }"
               v-model="email.value">
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>Your budget</h4>
        <p class="select">
          <select class="budget" v-model="selection.member">
                        <option value="0">$1500 > $4500</option>
                        <option value="0">$4500 > $10.000</option>
                        <option value="0">$10.000 > $20.000</option>
                        <option value="0">$20.000 > $50.000</option>
                    </select>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h4>Select your package</h4>

        <ul class="vue-form-list">
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-1" value="angular" 
                   v-model="selection.framework">
            <label for="radio-1">PWA for Proprietor</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-2" id="radio-2" value="react" 
                   v-model="selection.framework">
            <label for="radio-2">PWA for Business</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-3" id="radio-3" value="vue" 
                   v-model="selection.framework">
            <label for="radio-3">PWA for LLC</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-3" id="radio-3" value="vue" 
                   v-model="selection.framework">
            <label for="radio-3">PWA for INC</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h4>Features</h4>
        <ul class="vue-form-list">
          <li v-for="(feature, index) in features">
            <input type="checkbox" 
                   :value="feature" 
                   :id="'cb-feature-'+index" 
                   v-model="selection.features">
            <label :for="'cb-feature-'+index">{{feature}}</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-all" @click="checkAll">
            <label for="checkbox-all">Check All</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="label" for="textarea">Message with Counter</label>
        <textarea class="message" name="textarea" id="textarea" required="" 
                  v-model="message.text" 
                  :maxlength="message.maxlength"></textarea>
        <span class="counter">{{ message.text.length }} / {{ message.maxlength }}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Form">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <div class="debug">
    <pre><code>{{ $data }}</code></pre>
  </div>

</div>
</template>
```

### Script

```
    export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: {
        value: '',
        valid: true
      },
      features: ['Payment Gateway', 'Magento External Checkout', 'Logima Cloud Hosting', 'Google tracking', 'CSM extension', 'Other (Please specify in message)'],
      selection: {
        member: '0',
        framework: 'vue',
        features: []
      },
      message: {
        text: ``,
        maxlength: 1000
      },
      submitted: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // submit form handler
    submit: function () {
      this.submitted = true
    },
    // validate by type and value
    validate: function (type, value) {
      if (type === 'email') {
      }
    },
    // check for valid email adress
    isEmail: function (value) {
    },
    // check or uncheck all
    checkAll: function (event) {
      this.selection.features = event.target.checked ? this.features : []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    // watching nested property
    'email.value': function (value) {
      this.validate('email', value)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this should be two questions and not one. But since I know Magento and how VueSF works with it, I can help with point 2:

There is no API endpoint for magento contact form and there are few ways to do this:

- Create a magento plugin which provides API for sending requests to and connect vueSF to it (probably the hardest to create for non-magento dev)
- Create a simple script (separate from magento) which will accept vueSF requests and use the reuest data to send the emails with (probably the easiest to implement since you don't even have to have magento installed anywhere for this)
- Use an external service like https://formspree.io/ (just the first one I found on google, not advertising this particular one here)